# How to delete a part of line that has a specific beginning and ending on Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Let's say, for example, I have some HTML code consisting a lot of elements that looks like

```
<div id="1-element" class="1-element">...</div>
<div id="2-element" class="2-element">...</div>
...
<div id="99-element" class="99-element">...</div>
<div id="100-element" class="100-element">...</div>
...
```

I need to remove only all `class="*-element"` parts from the whole document but leave `div`s, `id`s and other stuff using regex in *Notepad++*. How am I able to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\bclass="\d+-element"
```

This should do it for you

Comment: It finds the whole line when it supposed to find a part of it. Clarified my question a little.

Comment: it works if there are no spaces inside but what should I do if there is something like `class="element *-element"` instead?

Comment: @Freeeeez use `\bclass="[^"]*element"`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

- In Notepad++, open Search windows, choose replace tab.
- Find what: `\sclass="\d+-element"`
- Check regular expression.
- Click Replace All.
- And the result:

<div id="1-element">...</div>

<div id="2-element">...</div>

<div id="99-element">...</div>

<div id="100-element">...</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex replacement:

**Find what**: `class="[^"]+-element"(?=[^>]*>)`

**Replace with**: empty string

Note that `[^"]+` will match anything, not just numbers before `-element` and `(?=[^>]*>)` lookahead will make sure we only remove `class` attribute inside a node.

[image]

Comment: It works too, sadly I can't mark 2 answers as right at the same time.

Comment: :) You should only mark the answer as accepted that worked for you best. I am glad vks' solution works, it is really not so probable that `class="ddd-element"` will appear in text, outside of an opening node. Although it might.